# BreezeJS and Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, breeze, azure-table-storage

In my current project, I would like to use BreezeJS with Azure Table Storage.

On the client side, I have AngularJS (using HotTowel template) and BreezeJS (DataService.js) which calls Asp.Net Web API 2 on server side. 
Web API interacts with Azure Table storage.

My questions are:

1. How can I produce metedata in web.api (BreezeController)?
2. Is there any ContextProvider for AzureTableStorage to provie metadata and CRUD operations?
3. Is there any Breezejs example which works with AzureTableStorage?

Comment: Hey @Tolga, did you ever figure this out? I'd like to do the same!

Answer (score 2):

For #1, take a look at the NoDb sample for an example of creating metadata "by hand".  This example shows how to create the metadata on the breeze client, but it could just as easily have been created on the server and sent to the client. Also you might want to look at these two articles.

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand and 
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool

As for Azure specifically, we don't yet have any examples, but please add this as a request to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  If it gets enough votes/interest we will produce an example.

Using Azure as your datastore should be very doable. So please post back with any progess on this front so that others can gain from your experience.